# Get object reference from its instance variable in c#?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to WPF application and also c#. I'll explain my situation:

I have a class called `myObject` which has an image instance variable of type `Image`
During runtime, I want to get the object reference of the `image` like:

```
myObject obj = new myObject();

Image img = obj.getImage();//reference to obj's image variable;
```

Now from `img` i want to get the object `obj`'s reference. How do I get this?

Edit: Below is a solution.

**Guys! First of all Thank you SO Much for all the help! I really appreciate! All of u rock!**

Following **Noob.net**'s advice, Whenever i create myObject obj, i stored the obj reference in **img.Tag** Property!

```
myObject obj = new myObject();
img.MouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(img_MouseLeftButtonDown);
Image img = obj.getImage();
```

The handler part:

```
Image i = (Image)sender;
myObject otemp = (myObject)i.Tag;// refers to the same object from which img was created
```

Comment: You don't.  It's not possible, unless the `Image` type was specifically designed to "remember" what created it.

Comment: Why do you need it? What are you trying to do actually? What problem do you have to keep the reference to `obj`?

Comment: No way. Period. Oh, you might traverse whole object tree testing each object living until you find a parent of the image... But that's **insanely** counter-productive.

Comment: Is `Image` the .NET `Image` class? Or is it a class you created?

Comment: @HighCore: What if `getImage` lazy loads the image?

Comment: @HighCore If `getImage` does complex image processing work (which seems likely enough) then it is appropriate to use a method, not a property, as a property getter ought to be quick and not contain complex logic or processing.  Also, the fact that he's using a method over a property is making you cry makes me cry, as the root problem of this question is much more fundamentally worrisome.

Comment: @servy (which Im sure it's not), but then it should be called `GetImage()`, not `getImage()`.

Comment: @HighCore Who cares, C# is the oddball there in that most every other language on earth doesn't capitalize method names.  I'm much more concerned that `myObject` isn't `MyObject`, as capitalizing class names is a much more common (and important) convention.  Method names aren't really ever ambiguous, unlike type names.

Comment: @servy you're right, but the OP states `I am new to WPF application and also c#. `. So that's why I linked to the `C# Properties` in MSDN so that he's aware they exist. Also, they're actually needed to perform any DataBinding in WPF.

Comment: @Servy C# doesn't care one way or the other how you spell your method names (and neither does Java). Whenever I have to go write Java code I almost always use C# naming conventions because it's what I'm used to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Tag property to store additional information about your Image instance

Comment: Thank you so much ! This is a very simple solution! It worked! :)

Comment: Just do not forget about possible boxing ;)

Answer (score 2):

The only way you can do this directly is if your `Image` type has a reference back to it's owner object. If you're talking about the `Image` type that's built into .NET then there's no such property.

You will have to take steps to record the parent object of each `Image` somewhere else where you can get back to it later. One common pattern would be to maintain a `HashTable` in memory where the `Image` object is the key and the `MyObject` object is the value.

Comment: (I initially recommended deriving a child class from `Image` but `Image` is abstract and `Bitmap` is sealed, so that isn't gonna work.)

Comment: Thanks a ton guys :) ! Cool, i guess i could update the dictionary with the corresponding reference whenever i create a new myObject and the image!

Comment: Keep in mind the images will hang around for as long as the `Dictionary<K,T>` or `Hashtable` does.

Answer (score 2):

If you follow the advice to put `Image` and `myObject` in a `Dictionary` together, you're going to have a bad time. Your images will live as long as the dictionary does and probably will not be disposed of in a timely fashion.

So why track this mapping using a data structure when you can structure your data to track the reference *by default*?

If you *wrap* the mapping in a [View Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel), you'll see what I mean:

```
public class MyObjectViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private myObject obj;

    public Image Image
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public MyObjectViewModel(myObject obj)
    {
        this.obj = obj;
        this.Image = obj.getImage();
    }

    public void SomethingThatMakesImageChange()
    {
        this.Image = obj.getImage();
        this.RaisePropertyChanged("Image");
    }

    // ... insert suitable INPC implementation ...
}
```

This approach has 2 distinct advantages:

1. Your View Models typically only live as long as your model does, which means the heavy `Image` class will only live as long as necessary in the view
2. If you need to adapt to real time changes to `myObject` instances, you can use your View Model to handle these changes and updates to the `Image` accordingly.

Comment: While this is clearly a problem you're having fun finding a solution for, odds are this isn't appropriate in context and there is a more fundamental problem with the design of the application that should be addressed, so I'd encourage the OP to think carefully before just copy-pasting a solution like this, even if it technically answers the question.

Comment: @Servy: while you commented I went ahead and added just that. And perhaps I'll go with your gut (interested parties can retrieve the changes from the edit history)

Answer (score 0):

Your `Image` class would have to have a `Parent` property that holds a reference back to your `myObject` instance. Then you'd have to make sure that when you set the image on `myObject` that you set the `Parent` property.

Now if you can't, or won't add a `Parent` property to the `Image` class, then your only option would be to compare instance of `myObject` with the `Image` to see if `myObject` contains it. If you have a collection of `myObject`, then this is fairly easy with Linq, but the performance may not be great.

Comment: Your second option assumes that `obj` knows whether or not it was the one that created some particular image.  That may not be true (in fact, I highly doubt it's true).

Comment: @Servy: I'm thinking of comparing references. Something like `if (obj.getImage() == thisImage)`. If it's the case that multiple `myObject` can hold references to the same image, then yeah, that doesn't work either. Or worse if `getImage` has side effects.

Comment: That's assuming that `getImage` is just a wrapper around an instance field and that it's returning a value, and not creating a new image.  The later is more likely in my eyes.  (At least, that's how I'd design it were it my program.)

Comment: @Servy: I think you're reading a lot more into than is actually there.

Answer (score 0):

I think I didnt understand, but here goes my answer:

```
public class MyObject
{
    private Image img;
    public Image Img
    {
        get { return img; }
        set { img = value; }
    }
    public MyObject()
    {
        Img = Image.FromFile("");
    }
}

public class Main
{
    MyObject obj = new MyObject();
    //obj.Img = Image.FromFile(""); //if u want
    Image image = obj.Img;
}
```

Comment: So how does one determine the `MyObject` that is the parent of the `Image` when given the `Image` instance?  In other words, you need to provide an implementation for `MyObject GetParent(Image image)`.  Given your code, it's not possible, so you haven't answered the question.